Git feature branch workflow with local configurations
I have a GitHub fork of a repository which I'm going to create a branch on to implement a particular feature. I hope that eventually this branch will be brought into the original repository. I have a couple of questions on the workflow.
I've created a local copy of this fork. Should the main (or master) branch be completely unchanged by me and always synced with the original?
The project is a multi-platform Flutter app. It requires some changes to be made to it to allow the project to be built on my machine and then be deployed to my testing device. Now, there are some files in the .gitignore which definitely are to do with local configuration, but I have a suspicion that some configuration files ARE tracked (perhaps accidentally by the original author).
Is the best practice to create a branch, lets say "local-config" that makes the necessary changes to run on my device, then create another branch that JUST implements the features, lets call it "feature" and then to test it, rebase "local-config" from "feature"?
This then allows me to test the feature branch on my local device, whilst being able to push the feature branch to the GitHub fork repository without adding the configuration-related files.

Have you tried asking your source project how they prefer to work?

I haven't. I wanted to maintain an air of professionalism haha. I'm a bit new to all of this. I thought that what I described might be standard practice.


Should the main (or master) branch be completely unchanged by me and always synced with the original?

tl;dr There's no need to maintain a "clean" main in a fork. Use origin/main.

If your forked version is just for the purposes of contributing back to the upstream project, leave main alone. Work in branches, issue pull requests to the upstream project, wait for them to be accepted, then git pull to update your main.
If you intend to use your forked version, then do the normal feature branch workflow on your project. Branch from main, work in branches, and merge them into main (it's often useful to use PRs even in personal own projects).
Upstream's version of main can be gotten from its remote tracking branch, origin/main. You can branch from this if you want to work on a "clean" contribution. You can git fetch origin to update origin/main. When you want to incorporate updates from upstream, you can git pull or merge origin/main into main.


It requires some changes to be made to it to allow the project to be built on my machine and then be deployed to my testing device.

These changes should be offered upstream. Or make an issue showing their project configuration is not flexible enough to accommodate your setup without code changes.

I have mentioned it to the source project and it's being considered. But it's tricky for them to do. They've only just introduced collaborators onto the project. Is there a workaround in the meantime? My suggestion isn't really working.

@oweydd A work around for the lack of configuration options? You're doing the work around, maintain your own fork while pushing for upstream change. What about that isn't working for you?

but I dont want to push changes that are just to do with setting up the configuration.

@oweydd Ideally, yes, these would be local changes on non-version controlled files. But the project doesn't support that. While you work on getting that fixed upstream, committing and pushing them to your own private fork is the next best thing. Is pushing these config changes to your local rep causing an issue?
